# Dynamically update CSS variables definitions in Tailwindcss during runtime

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css, css-variables

#### What I am trying to do?

I have a component library website where I want to show the different color themes. I have a select box where the user can switch between different themes.

I have two css files, lets name them watermelon and blueberry.

```
// blueberry/index/.css
:root {
--color-1: indigo;
}
```

```
// watermelon/index/.css
:root {
--color-1: green;
}
```

and on my tailwind.config.js

```
//tailwind.config.js
theme: {
 extend: {
  color: {
   primary: "var(--color-1)"
```

#### Whats happening on the code

I have a watcher on selectedTheme, so everytime value changes, I import the correct theme css file.

```
import { ref, watch } from "vue"

export default {
  setup() {
    const selectedTheme = ref("watermelon")
    const themeOptions = [
      { name: "Blueberry", value: "blueberry" },
      { name: "Watermelon", value: "watermelon" },
    ]
    async function importTheme(theme) {
      try {
        await import(`../themes/${theme}/index.css`)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    watch(
      selectedTheme,
      async newValue => {
        console.log("changing", newValue)
        await importTheme(newValue)
      },
      { immediate: true }
    )
    return { themeOptions, selectedTheme }
  },
}
</script>
<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

#### What is happening right now

On the first switch -> The theme is switched from watermelon to blueberry -> component color changes from green to indigo.

On second switch and after -> nothing happens, component color does not change.

I'm not sure what's happening here. Can someone enlighten me or point me to the right direction?

#### What is supposed to happen

Switching works even after the first. Switch from green to indigo and then back to green.

Comment: Does the console show the change?

Comment: @Dan, yep it does

Comment: @Dan my thought process right now is that whenever I import the new index.css, it overrides the previously imported index.css because the css variables have the same name.

1. On the first switch -> The theme is switched from watermelon to blueberry -> component color changes from green to blue.

2. On second switch and after -> nothing happens, component color does not change.

Comment: I'm guessing that once a CSS module is loaded, future reloads of that module are ignored.  Since unloading a CSS module is no trivial task, I would suggest rethinking the pattern.  For example, your themes could have differently named classes.  Or you could use a root element that changes class based on `selectedTheme`, and then each theme defines styles like:  `.indigo .mydiv {}`

Comment: @Dan, yep you are probably right, have read somewhere about using `document.documentElement.className` to set/update class on the root div instead. 

Anyways, thanks for the effort!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, something like `<div :class="selectedTheme">` would be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was declaring css variables like so:

```
.blueberry-theme {
 --color-1:indigo;
}
```

and

```
.watermelon-theme {
 --color-1: green;
}
```

and on the vue component watcher, I add a class to root element div using `document.documentElement.className` everytime selectedTheme is changed:

Example: if Blueberry is selected, "blueberry-theme" class is applied on the root div element.

```
<template>
  <Select :options="themeOptions" v-model="selectedTheme" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watch } from "vue"
export default {
  setup() {
    const selectedTheme = ref("blueberry-theme")

    const themeOptions = [
      { name: "Blueberry", value: "blueberry-theme" },
      { name: "Watermelon", value: "watermelon-theme" },
    ]

    function setTheme(theme) {
      document.documentElement.className = theme
    }

    watch(
      selectedTheme,
      async newValue => {
        await setTheme(newValue)
      },
      { immediate: true }
    )

    return { themeOptions, selectedTheme }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is what you want, but you can change css variables dynamically by doing:

```
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-1', someCoolColor)
  }
```

and this would be reflefect into tailwind styles that uses this variable.